# Add Another Icon Next to Close Icon in Lightbox Image Preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Im using Lightbox2 to preview my images, and I need to add a delete icon next to close image icon.

```
.row.flex-row.flex-nowrap.sidescroll.mx-1.my-4
  - @event.event_photos.approved.each do |p|
    = link_to p.photo.url, class: "event-photo mr-2", data: { lightbox: "event" } do
      = image_tag p.photo.url, height: 400`
```

[image]